# How to change the color of a bullet in a bullet list?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to change the colour of a bullet point using VBA, but keep getting stuck. I want to make all the bullet points in a bullet list blue instead of black.

Comment: Please take a moment to review the site guidelines for asking questions on Stack Overflow. This quesiton is too broad as well as unclear. At the very least, the code causing the problem should be included.

Answer (score 0):

In Word you can not simply set the `ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Font.Color` (as in PowerPoint), but assign another style, e. g.

```
Selection.ParagraphFormat.Style = "List with red buttons"
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be possible to loop through ListFormats/ListTemplates/ListLevels to update the font color and have it automatically apply to existing text.

However, for existing text, updating ListLevel.Font.Color from its Range object seems to work.

If you have already selected your list to update, you can use the following code. Note that you only need to have the cursor located somewhere in the list and it will update all bullet points in the list that are at the same level as the text where the cursor is placed. It also works on all point types including letters and numbers.

```
Selection.Range.ListFormat.ListTemplate.ListLevels(selection.Range.ListFormat.ListLevelNumber).Font.Color = vbBlue
```

If you want to update all bullet points at all levels in your document, you can loop through all paragraphs.

```
Dim pg as Paragraph
On Error Resume Next
For Each pg In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    pg.Range.ListFormat.ListTemplate.ListLevels(pg.Range.ListFormat.ListLevelNumber).Font.Color = vbBlue
Next
```

It you want to update only black bullet points (without updating bullet points that are already another color), then also check the existing color, which may be black because they're explicitly black (vbBlack) or because that's the default color (9999999):

```
Dim pg as Paragraph
On Error Resume Next
For Each pg In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    If pg.Range.ListFormat.ListTemplate.ListLevels(pg.Range.ListFormat.ListLevelNumber).Font.Color = vbBlack Or pg.Range.ListFormat.ListTemplate.ListLevels(pg.Range.ListFormat.ListLevelNumber).Font.Color = 9999999 Then
        pg.Range.ListFormat.ListTemplate.ListLevels(pg.Range.ListFormat.ListLevelNumber).Font.Color = vbBlue
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score -1):

[Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.paragraphformat.bullet) explains you alter its [ParagraphFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.paragraphformat), using code similar to:

```
With Application.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(2).TextFrame

    With .TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Bullet

        .Visible = True

        .RelativeSize = 1.25

        .Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 255)

    End With

End With
```

And, here's a [color picker](https://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.html) so you may get just the precise shade desired, translated into the [RGB format](https://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.html#rgb-format) (xxx,yyy,zzz) required.